# php xpath get correct content of div

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I want to parse my file "file.html":

```html
<div class="result">
    <p class="a">asdf</p>
</div>
<div class="result">
    <p class="a">hjkl</p>
    <p class="b">lkjh</p>
</div>
```

With the PHP code:

```html
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile(file.html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$entries = $xpath->query('//div[@class="result"]');

$i = 0;
foreach($entries as $entry) {
    $text_a[$i] = $xpath->query('//p[@class="a"]', $entry);
    $text_b[$i] = $xpath->query('//p[@class="b"]', $entry);
    $i++;
}
?>
```

I would like to ger for the 1. result only a text_a and in the second a text_a and text_b.

But unfortunately I get in the first result the content of class a and class b and in the second only the content of class a.

Does anybody know, how I could fix this problem?

Comment: So you're saying you get the *correct* results but in the wrong order? BTW, your HTML example is invalid HTML (mismatching end tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you have fallen for the common pitfall of using absolute XPaths where relative XPaths are needed.  Please try this:

```
$text_a[$i] = $xpath->query('p[@class="a"]', $entry);
$text_b[$i] = $xpath->query('p[@class="b"]', $entry);
```

Comment: His xpath queries are in the context of the entry node so the absolute path should work fine.

Comment: @kjetilh No, that's incorrect. Context is irrelevant when using absolute paths.

Comment: Hm you're probably right about the absolute path, not sure if the descendant path (which the OP is using) locates nodes relative to the context or the document root. Anyway, your solution seems to be most appropriate if he wants to find direct children of the nodes.

Comment: To answer my own question seems one needs a leading dot (.) to find descendant nodes relative to context node **.//descendant**.

Comment: In both cases `$xpath->query('p[@class="a"]', $entry)` and `.//descendant` I only get the content of the 2. result div

Comment: @user2154263 Could you post the code where you are using the `$text_a` and `$text_b` variables after they are populated? Your original description of the issue seems surprising, even with the absolute paths.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm using it later in a loop. I had there an error before. No it's working with both cases!! Thank you very much for your help.